# Insert 200 Million Rows from Staging Table to another Table in Same SQL Database

Tags: sql, insert

What is the quickest way without blowing up the transaction log?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you completely replacing the data or adding to it?

Answer (score 0):

The CTAS-create table as select probably is the fastest way to do such things on any DB.

Comment: The append hint seems to be related to ORACLE. I can't find anything for it with regards to sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

CTAS or create table as select statements are done as one transaction.

```
Create table new_table  
as  
select * from old_table
```

If you are inserting from the staging table into your base table this may be the fastest:

```
insert /*+ append */ into base_table  
values(select * from staging_table) ;
```

With the `append` hint you generate minimal logging, as such you **must** perform a backup immediately.